# How to connect a Java Swing application using Servlets to a server?

Tags: java, swing, servlets

I would like to connect my application via the internet to a server which has the MySQL Database.

How would I do that? And what's the Java `Servlet` to be used to connect?

Comment: I'm afraid you have completly misunderstood the concept of servlets.
Take a look at this first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think using barebone servlets is the best way to acheive what you want. I would do something like this:

- Create a new maven webapp archetype application
- Add MySQL dependency
- Add [RESTLet](http://restlet.org) or JAX-RS or Spring (version > 3.0) dependency and configure it to expose your data as RESTful web service. Lots of tutorials on the web.
- Use RESTLet client on your Swing application to invoke your service.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) or the more convenienced [Apache HttpComponents Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) to interact with arbitrary web resources.

#### See also:

- [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Answer (score 0):

The most "modern" way to do this is using RESTful web service. 
I do not know how is your server side code built, but if I start to develop from scratch I'd use Spring framwork that has perfect support of REST web services.